# Encode/Decode base64

Tags: base64, go

here is my code and I don't understand why the decode function doesn't work.

Little insight would be great please.

```
func EncodeB64(message string) (retour string) {
    base64Text := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(message)))
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(base64Text, []byte(message))
    return string(base64Text)
}

func DecodeB64(message string) (retour string) {
    base64Text := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(message)))
    base64.StdEncoding.Decode(base64Text, []byte(message))
    fmt.Printf("base64: %s\n", base64Text)
    return string(base64Text)
}
```

It gaves me :
[Decode error - output not utf-8][Decode error - output not utf-8]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`DecodedLen` returns the **maximal** length.

This length is useful for sizing your buffer but part of the buffer won't be written and thus won't be valid UTF-8.

You have to use only the real written length returned by the `Decode` function.

```
l, _ := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(base64Text, []byte(message))
log.Printf("base64: %s\n", base64Text[:l])
```

Answer (score 62):

The len prefix is superficial and causes the invalid utf-8 error:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/base64"
        "fmt"
        "log"
)

func main() {
        str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("Hello, playground"))
        fmt.Println(str)

        data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("error:", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%q\n", data)
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/GzwqG5IjsA))

---

Output

```
SGVsbG8sIHBsYXlncm91bmQ=
"Hello, playground"
```

EDIT: I read too fast, the len was not used as a prefix. dystroy got it right.

Answer (score 27):

To sum up the other two posts, here are two simple functions to encode/decode Base64 strings with Go:

```
// Dont forget to import "encoding/base64"!

func base64Encode(str string) string {
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(str))
}

func base64Decode(str string) (string, bool) {
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str)
    if err != nil {
        return "", true
    }
    return string(data), false
}
```

[Try it!](https://play.golang.org/p/of1EjpKUlk)

Answer (score 4):

@Denys Séguret's answer is almost 100% correct. As an improvement to avoid wasting memory with non used space in `base64Text`, you should use [base64.DecodedLen](https://golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go#L607). Take a look at how [base64.DecodeString](https://golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go#L374) uses it. 
It should look like this:

```
func main() {
    message := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("Hello, playground"))

    base64Text := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(message)))

    n, _ := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(base64Text, []byte(message))
    fmt.Println("base64Text:", string(base64Text[:n]))
}
```

Try it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/IA9g1-LhSX7).

Answer (score 3):

More or less like above, but using []bytes and part of a bigger struct:

```
func (s secure) encodePayload(body []byte) string {
  //Base64 Encode
  return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(body)
}

func (s secure) decodePayload(body []byte) ([]byte, error) {
  //Base64 Decode
  b64 := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(body)))
  n, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(b64, body)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return b64[:n], nil
}
```