# How to decode base64 from tendermint's GET tx responce

Tags: go, base64, tendermint

I queried a transaction result using:

> *http://localhost:26657/tx?hash=0x43B8422E9FD4FD4A01213772E989CDA5F36103A0EA679B95932052B20C016267*

and then fetch the transaction content 'tx' in the returned JSON object.

> *rgEoKBapCjZS59jqCgpnb29nbGUuY29tEg4KCW5hbWV0b2tlbhIBNRoUr67sqicZ8wXbWkNLD8E6c0TGM/YSBBDAmgwaagom61rphyEC6ICqudQCIugpL8NEvi6Fblxk+ZB+51T+NUDg0WdMQCUSQG0z4HhxINONIjPcQc/GDyVOjU9CRovZaT3GxcekSvN6SBQx94xgwMkq7EqivCxSqYB/TDC0Gp5Z/6z2+Z4Km3k=*

I decoded this with

`base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(base64Str)`

and then it printed the following result

> �((� 6R���
>
> google.com
>           ┼▒└␊├⎺┐␊┼5���'��ZCK�:sD�3���
>                                       j &�Z�!耪��"�)/�D�.�n\d��~�T�5@��gL@%@m3�xq
>   Ӎ"3�A��%N�OBF��i=��ǤJ�zH1��`��*�J��,R��L0��Y����� �y

What's the correct way to decode a transaction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334220/encode-decode-base64
is working for you?

Comment: Manjeet Thakur, no i already tried, i think this base64 something else encoded

Comment: BDW Your output is correct.

Comment: No it isn't, i think that the output can be encoded too

Comment: If DecodeString doesn't return an error, it succeeded, whether you believe it or not. What makes you think that it's not working?

Comment: Because i wait readable JSON, but have many incorrect symbols

Comment: Your Go code is fine, the `rgEoK [..] m3k=` string just isn't JSON data. Either you have an error somewhere in your code, or you have a problem with the Tendermint API. Having the full Go code ([mcve]) would be useful.

Comment: I solved this problem. Tendermint's api sent encoded string and before decoding with base64 I must decode this one with tendermint's codec because i used Cosmos SDK and this message was encoded when i sent transaction with Cosmos SDK's tools